# Puma fails sometimes with ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, activeadmin, puma

I am using the Puma webserver and ActiveAdmin. When trying to load an active admin page of users in production I get a 502 error about 1/4 times. How can I correct this bug?

**The screen shows this:**

```
502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.8.0
```

**The logs show this:**

```
2016-02-17T20:05:47.175Z - app I, [2016-02-17T20:05:47.194213 #15715]  INFO -- : Started GET "/admin/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-17 20:05:47 +0000
2016-02-17T20:05:47.178Z - app I, [2016-02-17T20:05:47.196358 #15715]  INFO -- : Processing by Admin::UsersController#index as HTML
2016-02-17T20:05:54.579Z - app [69] - Worker 0 (pid: 15959) booted, phase: 0
```

**config/puma.rb**

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Comment: No error message. All I get in the logs, from request to fail, are those three lines above.

Comment: what error message do you see in the logs when the error happens? You might need to increase the log level to get more information

Comment: I recently switched to :info from :debug, but the logs stayed the same. No error message.

Comment: are you using a web server on top of Puma? Like nginx? Have you checked the error logs there?

Comment: I'm using catalyze.io, which uses nginx. I can talk to them, but otherwise I'm not sure how to view the nginx logs.

Comment: I think you should. There should be important info in the `error.log` from nginx. In general this looks like there's a very slow page in activeadmin (which is normal, it runs a lot of db queries by default, but can be configured easily), and I think this page is causing a timeout, so nginx tries to connect to puma, but it's unavailable serving other requests. Performance tools like NewRelic can also help you debug this

Comment: No errors on New Relic, but it does look like CPU use spikes and memory usage grows significantly as well when I hit this page.